# Hiding Tooltips Inside iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have 2 files.  Here they are:

**website-page.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Test Layout</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
            body, html
            {
                margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; overflow: hidden;
            }

            #content
            {
                position:absolute; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; top: 0px; 
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" src="iframe.html" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**iframe.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Test iFrame</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <p>This is a test page.</p>
             <button type="button" title="Test Title Tag">Click Me!</button> 
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see, `website-page.html` includes an iFrame to the `iframe.html` file.  I CAN edit the `website-page.html` file, but I CANNOT edit the `iframe.html` file.

When I hover, over the button, I see the `title` attribute popup that says `Test Title Tag`.

**What javascript, jquery, or css code can be added to the `website-page.html` page to hide this attribute so it doesn't popup?**  I've found several jquery solutions, but none seem to work when the content is being loaded through the iframe.

Comment: is the iframe page from another domain?

Comment: Yes, the iframe is hosted on a different domain.

Comment: You can't access it due to *"same origin policy"* unless you can edit the code in it

Comment: So it wouldn't even be possibly to completely disable tooltips from showing regardless of if they are in an iframe or not?

Comment: out of iframe sure...remove the title with simple script